# Probability Past 100%?

Tags: probability

Let's say I have a 100-sided dice. The dice contains 99 red spots, and 1 green spot. I roll the dice 100 times, but I never roll a green. What is the probability of me rolling a green on my next roll?

Comment: 1 in 100, since the events are independents.

Comment: Depends on whether the die is "fair" and is rolled fairly. If those are the case, the probability is $1/100$.  Or maybe not. Maybe the die is thinking to itself, poor Dane, he has bet on green $99$ times, and lost, giving up his car, and his house. Now he has wagered his left kidney on green. I owe it to him to go green. If the die has those kinds of feelings for you, the probability of green might be higher than $0.01$.

Comment: I suppose this is some variation of the Monty Hall Problem. If that is true 1/100 cannot be the answer.

Comment: Eh, I take that back... That implies a first pick, or a first roll, so nevermind.

Comment: Not the Monty Hall problem, but the gambler's fallacy.

Comment: It's nothing to do with the Monty Hall problem - there's no third party or otherwise an appreciation of some extra knowledge about the game. It's the same die it always was. Further, there's no choice involved in the roll of a die.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Thanks

Comment: @AndréNicolas If you ever meet a die like that then immediately let me know, okay?! Reading your comment my sympathy for it was growing exponentially. :)

Comment: Also note that a probability is a number between $0$ and $1$. The title of your question suggested otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question could be interpreted in two ways:

The obvious one is that the probability that is sought is to get a green dot for the next roll, which, since the rolls themselves have no causal relation, i.e. they are independent, and assuming that the dice is fair, you will receive:

$ p(X="green-dot") = 1/100 $

Another way to understand your inquiry would be to ask for the probability of rolling $99$ red dots in a row and *then* rolling a green dot. This probability would be:

$ p(X="99 red-dots, then-1-green-dot") = 99^{99}/100^{100} = 0.003697...$

As you see, neither one of them is $ > 1 $. Does that solve your question?

Answer (score 4):

The probability of you getting a green on the next roll is $\frac{1}{100}$, see [Gambler's fallacy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambler%27s_fallacy)